# Liquibase Exception with MongoDB using Liquibase Image

Tags: mongodb, liquibase

**USE CASE**

Use liquibase for versioning of Mongo DB

**ISSUE**

I am getting the following exception while running liquibase update command

```
[2023-01-18 23:47:35] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] class liquibase.database.core.UnsupportedDatabase cannot be cast to class liquibase.nosql.database.AbstractNoSqlDatabase (liquibase.database.core.UnsupportedDatabase is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @7d4793a8; liquibase.nosql.database.AbstractNoSqlDatabase is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @aed0151)
liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class liquibase.database.core.UnsupportedDatabase cannot be cast to class liquibase.nosql.database.AbstractNoSqlDatabase (liquibase.database.core.UnsupportedDatabase is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @7d4793a8; liquibase.nosql.database.AbstractNoSqlDatabase is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @aed0151)
```

Some lines above the logs i also find one warning
`[2023-01-18 23:47:35] WARNING [liquibase.database] Unknown database: MongoDB`

**Context**

I am using Liquibase CLI command to run my changelog on MongoCluster. Here is my command

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<jaas.conf> -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true && liquibase --changelog-file=changelog-root.xml  --url="mongodb://<USER>@<DB Host>:<Port>/<db name>?connectTimeoutMS=300000&authMechanism=GSSAPI&authSource=%24external" --classpath=liquibase_libs/liquibase-mongodb-4.14.0.jar:liquibase_libs/bson-4.6.1.jar:liquibase_libs/mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:liquibase_libs/mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.1.jar --driver=liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoClientDriver --logLevel=debug --hub-mode=OFF update
```

Given liquibase core doesn't have support for MongoDB, i am using Liquibase ext driver for connecting with Mongo as evident from the command shared above. Can someone please throw some light on what could be the possible reason of the exception i am getting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what my class path looks like

`classpath=changelog:classpath/liquibase-mongodb-4.21.0.jar:classpath/bson-4.8.1.jar:classpath/mongodb-driver-core-4.8.1.jar:classpath/mongodb-driver-sync-4.8.1.jar:classpath/jackson-core-2.11.3.jar:classpath/jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar:classpath/jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar:classpath/snakeyaml-1.27.jar`

I was only able to get it working using the `4.18 liquibase` docker image and previous versions. I kept running into multiple issues when using `.xml` and `.yaml` changelogs all pointing out to a "possible missing" liquibase commercial license, even when trying some examples form inside the liquibase-mongodb extension.